# $Date.Format on Silverstripe 4 Template

Tags: date, silverstripe, date-format, silverstripe-4

I have a date in the database with this format "YY-mm-dd". On the template I want it in this format: dd.mm.YY
Usually it would work with $date.Format('d.m.Y')
But not in Silverstripe 4. It converts from 2018-05-08 to 8.0.2018. Only the year is correct. Was there a change. I didn't find anything in the Documentation

Answer (score 16):

Date formats in SS4 were changed from PHP date formatting to [CLDR date formatting](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#date-field-symbol-table) ([changelog link](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/changelogs/4.0.0#overview-general)):

> Changed Format() method to use CLDR format strings, rather than PHP format string. E.g. d/m/Y H:i:s (php format) should be replaced with to dd/MM/y HH:mm:ss (CLDR format).

You can use this to achieve what you want:

```
$Date.Format('dd.MM.y')
```

Comment: this makes me a n g e r e y

Comment: What's worse is that their so called "documentation" is silent on these issues. It "documents" the parameter as literally "the format string".... you don't say Sherlock...

Comment: Is there no way to change the default formatting in SS4 via config? That way we can retain backward compatibility more easily without having to revise every instance.

Comment: You’d need to replace a bunch of core classes, and third party modules would then break unless you built your adapter to handle both formats. Better to bite the bullet IMO

Comment: Sometimes its really hard just to find basic documentation like this on simple formatting.